# while loop with or condition

Tags: python, while-loop, logical-operators

in the second while loop i am stuck and never gets out of there. how to fix?

```
def playGame(wordList):

new_hand = {}

choice = input('Enter n to deal a new hand, or e to end game: ')   
while choice != 'e':
    if choice == 'n':
        player_or_pc = input('Enter u to have yourself play, c to have the computer play: ')
        while player_or_pc != 'u' or player_or_pc != 'c':
            print('Invalid command.')
            player_or_pc = input('Enter u to have yourself play, c to have the computer play: ')                  
        if player_or_pc == 'u':
            print('player played the game')
        elif player_or_pc == 'c':
            print('PC played the game')
        choice = input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ')
    else:
        print('Invalid command.')
        choice = input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last hand, or e to end game: ')
```

Comment: `player_or_pc != 'u' or player_or_pc != 'c'` - This condition will *always* be true.  Sounds like you want an `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 4):

`player_or_pc != 'u' or player_or_pc != 'c'` is *always true*:

- if `player_or_pc` is `'u'`, it is not equal to `'c'`, so one of the two conditions is true
- if `player_or_pc` is `'c'`, it is not equal to `'u'`, so one of the two conditions is true
- any other value *both* conditions are true

Use `and`:

```
while player_or_pc != 'u' and player_or_pc != 'c':
```

or use `==`, put the whole in parentheses, and use `not` in front:

```
while not (player_or_pc == 'u' or player_or_pc == 'c'):
```

at which point it is clearer to use a membership test:

```
while player_or_pc not in {'u', 'c'}:
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
while player_or_pc != 'u' or player_or_pc != 'c':
```

with

```
while player_or_pc != 'u' and player_or_pc != 'c':
```

Otherwise, `player_or_pc` should equals `u` and `c` and that's not possible.